# Fluid divs around image

Tags: html, css

I want to have a shape under website logo but it needs to be continued from both sides by orange bars so it would look as a one piece. Here is [the preview](http://jumbo.elique.cz/)  that I've created so far.

I'm stucked on this for hours. Please do you have idea how to accomplish that and keep it responsible? Thank you!

Here is how it should look like.
[image]

Comment: The simplest approach would be to use a background image (PNG type with transparent section) and the HTML needs to be designed accordingly.

Comment: Sure, but how? I've tried table design, I've tried to make a wide background image and set the right position with percentage - that was the closest solution, but it was resizing (changing position) little bit different than other elements... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background color of `.test` to the solid color in your background image, then position it properly. Lastly set the logo to `position: absolute` (don't worry it wont move unless you give it a position) then set the `z-index: 2;` to raise it above the squiggle.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/bge8hjLf/))

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('//jumbo.elique.cz/img/navbar-bottom.png');
    width: 345px;
    height: 34px;
    top: 64px;
    background-color: #0b1b33;
}
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Now this may cause the background color to cover up some of the busses in the background, to fix this you can wrap the nav in a `100px` tall div with the same background-color, making this more uniform

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/bge8hjLf/1/))

```
.wrap {
    background-color: #0b1b33;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I thought it's gonna be tough, I'll kill the designer! :) It looks OK. I'll use it, I'm sure there isn't better solution. Thank you very much for your time!